# Error in Selenium Maven and Jenkins integration

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins-plugins

I am a New to integrating selenium code built using Maven and integrating with selenium.  My selenium code works fine in local through TestNG but while integrating with Jenkins or running as a Maven build its throwing the below error.

I have tried updating Maven and also mvn clean install. but nothing is working out

Am i using wrong versions of jars for selenium, extent reports, poi etc.. Attaching my pom.XML and error for your reference

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project Selenium: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] Cannot instantiate class executionEngine.DriverScriptTest
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:31)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:332)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:81)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:98)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:119)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:353)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:227)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:197)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:142)
```

Below is my POM.XML file

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>Automation</groupId>
      <artifactId>Selenium</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>Selenium</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
       <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>forplay-legacy</id>
          <url>http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>
      <properties>
    <suiteXmlFile>C:/Users/ADC_2/eclipse-workspace/Selenium_workingcode_1026/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </properties>
    <build>

    <plugins>

    <plugin>

    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>

    <suiteXmlFiles>
    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
     <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration> 
    </plugin>

    </plugins>

    </build>

    </project>
```

Comment: few things, (1) version mismatch of surefire plugin in logs to pom. (2) junit, as well as testng in pom, is not a good sign for test dependencies

Comment: I have tried changing surefire plugin version multiple times, still getting this error.. so with the current pom.xml given above I am getting the below error[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project Selenium: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Cannot instantiate class executionEngine.DriverScriptTest